# Capybara with headless chrome doesn't clear session between test cases which use different subdomains

Tags: session, selenium-webdriver, capybara, google-chrome-headless

I switched my rails tests from capybara-webkit to headless chrome. When I run a test which visits not the default Capybara host the first case passes but the second one fails because the user are already logged in when they try to login

I use `chromedriver v2.45`, `selenium-webdriver (3.141.0)` and `capybara (2.18.0)`

I have the following setup:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
    args: %w[headless disable-gpu no-sandbox]
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

I tried to change the app host to the default domain after visiting another domain

```
using_app_host("http://another.lvh.me") do
  visit '/'

  # do something
end
```

where `using_app_host` is

```
def using_app_host(host)
  original_host = Capybara.app_host
  Capybara.app_host = host
  yield
ensure
  Capybara.app_host = original_host
end
```

but it didn't help.

The spec structure looks the following way:

```
feature "Use another subdomain", js: true do
  before { login } # use default Capybara app host http://root.lvh.me

  scenario "case 1" do
    using_app_host("http://another.lvh.me") do
      # do something
    end
  end

  scenario "case 2" do
    using_app_host("http://another.lvh.me") do
      # do something else
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas why capybara/headless chrome doesn't clean the user session between the test cases when navigating to another domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you storing session information in the browsers `window.localStorage` and/or `window.sessionStorage`? If so you can set those to be cleared via options passed to the driver (Note: these  settings are the default for the selenium driver in Capybara 3.12+)

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(args: %w[no-sandbox])
  options.headless!
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options, clear_local_storage: true, clear_session_storage: true)
end
```

Comment: hi Thomas, I tried to add `clear_local_storage: true, clear_session_storage: true` but it didn't help. Seems like that the issue is reproducible only when spec cases use different host (not the default Capybara host). I updated the question

Comment: @Hirurg103 Are you sure that stored info in local/session storage is actually your issue?  Assuming you are actually storing info in either local or session storage Capybara can only reset the storage for the subdomain it's on when the session is reset.  If you need it cleared for other subdomains you'd need to manually visit them and call `page.driver.browser.local_storage/session_storage.clear` (Selenium specific) - Not also that in Capybara 3.12 `clear_local_storage: true, clear_session_storage: true` is the default behavior so doesn't need to be set

Comment: @Hirurg103 Also, if it really is local/session storage on root.lvh.me that needs resetting (and nothing needs to be reset on  another.lvh.me) another option would be to visit a page at root.lvh.me/whatever before ending the test - so that is the active subdomain when Capybara resets the session.

Comment: Hi Thomas, actually I upgraded capybara to `v3.12` and the issue has gone. Before I was using capybara `v2.18`. Now I don't need to change session name with `Capybara.session_name = :another` before I visit `http://another.lvh.me`. Also I don't need to reset sessions with `Capybara.reset_sessions!` after each test case. Maybe capybara `v2.18` is not fully compatible with `chrome-72.0.3626.28-beta` and `chromedriver-2.45` and doesn't reset the session correctly? What do you think?

Comment: @Hirurg103 Capybara 3.12 changed to clear session and local storage by default, and with Chrome it's able to clear cookies for all domains (pure webdriver can only clear for the current domain, Capybara does something special when using Chrome though).  It's possible your issue had nothing to do with session/local storage and was purely cookie based.

Comment: Thomas yes, I agreed. I am using `sorcery` gem for auhentication and `redis_store` to store the user session. But the session key is being stored in the browser cookies which I guess was not reset for the main host `http://root.lvh,me` after spec case in which user visited `http://another.lvh.me`

Comment: you might update the answer with the information that capybara `v3.12` clears session and storage out of the box and I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

Even I was facing same issue.

After adding the steps to clear the cookies, session it is not working either. I added below code in env.rb to start a new session every time for a new test

May be you can try this.

```
Before do
  Capybara.session_name = ":session_#{Time.zone.now.to_i}" 
end

After do
  Capybara.current_session.driver.quit
end
```

Also, you can add in chrome options to open the session in incognito window

Comment: Hi Kiran, I tried your solution but it didn't help. Seems like that the issue is reproducible only when user visits another host (not the default Capybara app host) in the spec cases. I updated the question accordingly

Comment: Very helpful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread useful in a reverse context. I have a test setup wherein I'm storing session credentials in local storage. And so upgrading from capybara v3.11 to v3.12 broke the suite such that only the first scenario would pass and the rest of the scenarios would fail on the login page every time. 
That's because the local storage was getting cleared based on the default behavior of capybara 3.12

I updated my suite to set clear_local_storage and clear_session_storage to false explicitly at time of registering the driver.

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, 
                                   browser: :chrome, 
                                   clear_local_storage: false, 
                                   clear_session_storage: false)
```