# Capybara does not completely reset when visit different URL than app_host

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

I am new to Capybara so I may miss something obvious but I am not sure what is going on. I have three test cases in the same suite with app_host set to URL A.

Test1: Visit website A which then redirects to website B and requires log in to B.

Test2: Visit website B and perform some tests

Test3: Visit website B and perform some tests.

In test 2 and 3, I use visit with absolute URL to visit website B and the code is identical. In test 2, I don't have to log in but in test 3, website B redirects to the log in page.

I found a similar issue here: [Capybara with headless chrome doesn't clear session between test cases which use different subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53390321/capybara-with-headless-chrome-doesnt-clear-session-between-test-cases-which-use) but after updating from 2.8 to 3.9, I still have the same issue.
I also tried to Capybara.reset_sessions! and Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.delete_all_cookies after each test without success.

I am using Capybara 3.29.0 and Selenium-webdriver 3.142.6. The Chrome driver is in a docker image selenium/standalone-chrome:3.14.0-iron.

Driver registration:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  chrome_capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
  chromeoptions: {
      args: %w[headless no-sandbox disable-gpu --window-size=1024,1024]
  })
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
    browser: :remote,
    :url => 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    :desired_capabilities => chrome_capabilities)
end
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
```

Any idea what cause the difference in behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using massively out of date versions of Capybara and selenium-webdriver.  The WebDriver protocol only allows for resetting the cookies of the host you're on when `reset` occurs, so if you're moving between hosts the cookies for only one of them are going to get cleared.  If, however, you switch to using a recent version of Capybara with a recent version of selenium-webdriver and Chrome then Capybara will clear cookies for all hosts (using CDP)

Comment: Thank you. Do you happen to know which version of Capybara starts offering that? Also if Capybara used to only clear out cookies for one of the hosts, if I set app_host to website B, why wont Capybara clear out cookies for website B?

Comment: @user1927182 it would  clear for whatever host it’s on at the end of the test -  I don’t remember what version it was added in, but it also required selenium-webdriver to support CDP commands which was 3.141 or 3.142 iirc -just update both to latest

Comment: Update capybara to 3.29 and selenium-webdriver to 3.142 and still have the same issue. Do I have to explicitly do something to reset cookies?

Comment: @user1927182 shouldn’t have to - what is your driver registration? What version of chromedriver and chrome?

Comment: Update the main post with info about driver registration.

Comment: OH - you’re using a remote driver - I don’t think that will support CDP calls until 4.0 - if it is supported it would only be in the latest release which isn’t 3.14 (which I assume is what selenium/standalone-chrome:3.14.0-iron contains

Comment: Never mind. My environment just cached it somehow. Clearing out everything after updating fixed the issue for me.